# How to calculate the average per day for different years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the average number of times `apple` with an increment of `3` are shown per day in the years of both `2018` and `2017`. To do this I am trying to use `setNum` and `exNum` that has a difference of `3`.

```
ID     Year           Text      setNum    ExNum
-------------------------------------------------
1      2018-01-21     apple       1         3
2      2017-08-03     apple       2         5
3      2018-03-02     banana      1         3
4      2018-05-22     apple       1         3
5      2018-12-12     apple       3         6
6      2017-04-13     apple       3         6
```

My current query to obtain this is:

```
SELECT
    2017 = avg(case when Year BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' then 1 else 0 end),
    2018 = avg(case when Year BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM
    exampleTable
WHERE
    Text LIKE '%apple%'
```

This  currently outputs:

```
2017  2018
 0     0
```

Note: The original table had a single text column `Increment`, which had values like `1-3`.  That is, the `1-3` represented a `setNum` of 1 and an `ExNum` of 3.

Comment: What is the expected output? What does average mean?

Comment: what is the meaning `with an increment of 3 `

Comment: An increment of 3 as in the average's I am looking for have a difference of `3` between them.

Comment: You generally should _not_ change your question after people have answered, especially if that would invalidate the answers already given.

Comment: Average of _what_? Apple appears 2 times in 2017, 3 in 2018 (3 out of 4 total). What would the average be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decision to store a numerical increment range as text is not a good one, and ideally you should be storing the two points of the increment in separate columns.  That being said, we can do some string olympics to work around this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Year) AS Year,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN 3 BETWEEN CAST(LEFT(Increment, CHARINDEX('-', Increment)-1) AS int) AND
              CAST(RIGHT(Increment, LEN(Increment) - CHARINDEX('-', Increment)) AS int)
               THEN 1 END) AS apple_3_cnt
FROM exampleTable
WHERE
    TEXT LIKE '%apple%'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(year);
```

[image]

### Demo

Here I am aggregating by year, and then taking a conditional count of record, for each year, where the apple increment range contains 3.  To do this, I separate out the two ends of the increment range, and then convert them to integers.

**Edit:**

Based on your updated table, we can try a simpler query:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Year) AS Year,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN 3 BETWEEN setNum AND ExNum THEN 1 END) AS apple_3_cnt
FROM exampleTable
WHERE
    TEXT LIKE '%apple%'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(year);
```

Comment: I updated my table to benefit using a value as the increment range rather than text, how would you use both `setNum` `exNum` to calculate the average.

Comment: Yep this is working thanks heaps, one little thing how would I get it to output the way I want it to (see the current output I have above). Another thing, If I were to add more Years to my table, how would I make it only show specific years.

Comment: @Blake [Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a110574c2ffc4726a4d29c479f37abe) with those requirements.  We can just aggregate over the entire table in this case.  I included a check on the year.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT
    avg(case when Year BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' then setNum+ExNum end) as 2017 
    avg(case when Year BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' then setNum+ExNum end) as 2018
FROM
    exampleTable
WHERE
    Text LIKE '%apple%'
```

Comment: Using count will give me the total not the average which is what I am attempting to get.

Comment: @Blake, I've modified my answer, you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine. The only problem is how and to where you assign the results.
Use this syntax instead

```
SELECT
 avg(case when Year BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as A2017,
 avg(case when Year BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as A2018
FROM
    exampleTable
WHERE
    Text LIKE '%apple%'
```

Note that you can't use numbers as variable names.